# How do I get this jQuery parallax Slider to do infinite looping?

Tags: jquery, slider, parallax

I'm using this [jquery parallax slider](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ParallaxSlider/) that works brilliantly. Though it's leaving me with little wiggle room to edit any of what I'm looking to do.

I think this is the simplest question: When the slides reach the end how do I get it to swing back to slide 1 like this great example [here](http://bxslider.com/).

So far this is the greatest example of a auto scrolling parallax slide I have. Anyone with a better demo please help. I have been at this for days.

Comment: Your questions title appears in conflict with the body. Do you want 'infinite' looping, or do you want it to stop at the ends? Have you tried setting the `circular` option to false?

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to edit my question accordingly. Yes, I have set circular to false. Setting that option just doesn't allow for the user to swing back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Set o.circular to false and it won't keep looping around

```
$.fn.parallaxSlider.defaults = {
    auto            : 0,
    speed           : 1000,
    easing          : 'jswing',
    easingBg        : 'jswing',
    circular        : false,
    thumbRotation   : true
};
```

Comment: Thanks @JimP, when you flag it as false it doesn't loop, it stops the functionality of '$pxs_next'.

Comment: @ HQ101 What exactly are you looking to accomplish with this?  If you set circular to false it will progress through the slides until the end and it will stop (not loop back to the first image).  The user can then reverse course through the gallery or select any image individually.  Is that not what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is simply having the last slide, say slide 5, on hit will slide to 1. So its- 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. I'm sorry my originally stated question is confusing. The way it goes now is 1->2->3->4->5-> 4>>3>>2>> 1

Comment: Ok.  I see where you're going.  In the demo it looks like you can just leave it set to circular: true.  My local copy was spinning back around to the first image.  Maybe compare the demo code against your local and see if an increment in the options got converted to a decrement? 
In the demo code 

....
$pxs_next.bind('click',function(){
  ++current;            if(current >= total_elems)           if(o.circular)         current = 0;        else{  ....

takes care of resetting the image counter